# A try-catch one liner (like "??" or ternary operator)

Tags: c#, exception, null-coalescing-operator

So we have ternary operators. Great! Then there's the `??` operator, which does a coalesce over a `nullable` variable.

Example:

```
string emptyIfNull = strValue ?? "";
```

**Question:** Is it possible to implement a simple operator like this for a try-catch?

Example:

```
string result = CoalesceException(someExpression, "");

public static T CoalesceException<T>(expression, defaultValue)
{
    try
    {
        return evaluate expression; // ?
    }
    catch
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement a method that can be used as easily as possible, or even some kind of coalesce-like operator?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to? you should be trying to catch specific exceptions first, and then you shouldn't be using try catch to determine program flow either

Comment: For instance, if you loop through processes'es `MainModule`, you get exceptions for all **x64** processes. This is where this "operator" would kick in. It's for inline exception handling where no specific info about the exception (or bubbling) is necessary.

Comment: But then you are covering up an issue you have, you know that your program has an issue with x64 processes so you should try to fix those. If an exception has occured, then something has gone wrong and the time should be taken to handle it, so I don't think there is any shortcut that should be taken :)

Comment: I don't want to discuss specific examples in which this is useful or if it is useful at all. I'm just looking for a proper way to implement this.

Comment: You have `try? fooThatCanThrow ?? defaultValue` in Swift, but not yet in C#. At least, nullability was added in C# 8.0, so it's a step closer to have your short syntax one day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can:

```
public static T CoalesceException<T>(Func<T> func, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    try
    {
        return func();
    }
    catch
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure this is what you want...

use:

```
string emptyIfError = CoalesceException(() => someExpressionThatReturnsAString, "");
```

for example...

```
string shortString = null;

string emptyIfError = CoalesceException(() => shortString.Substring(10), "");
```

will return `""` instead of `NullReferenceException`

**important**

The function, as written, will cause the "evaluation" of `defaultValue` always. Meaning:

```
string Throws() { throw new Exception(); }

string str1 = somethingTrue == true ? "Foo" : Throws();
```

Here an exception won't be thrown, because `Throws()` won't be evalued. The same happens with the `??` operator.

```
string str2 = CoalesceException(() => ((string)null).ToString(), Throws());
```

This **will** cause an exception before entering in `CoalesceException`. Solution:

```
public static T CoalesceException<T>(Func<T> func, Func<T> defaultValue = null)
{
    try
    {
        return func();
    }
    catch
    {
        return defaultValue != null ? defaultValue() : default(T);
    }
}
```

Use:

```
string emptyIfError = CoalesceException(() => someExpressionThatReturnsAString, () => "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a little something that I've end up, to create a One Liner TryCatch

**Usage**

```
  var r = Task.TryCatch(() => _logic.Method01(param1, param2));
```

**TryCatch definition**

```
public static class Task
{

    public static TResult TryCatch<TResult>(Func<TResult> methodDelegate)
    {
        try
        {
            return methodDelegate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // .. exception handling ...
        }

        return default(TResult);
    }
}
```